# typescript constructor won't let me define anything

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to write a basic class in typescript using ionic 2.  Here's my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {FishPage} from '../fish';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.salary = 7;
  }

}
```

The typescript is not compiling.  I am getting this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'salary' does not exist on type 'HomePage'.

How do I define salary in the constructor?

Comment: Try declaring it outside the constructor before assigning it a value inside the constructor.  `salary:number; constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){ this.salary = 7;}`

Comment: declare that variable. something like this:
 salay:number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class member need to be defined, either in the constructor signature using public/protected/private (as you did with the `navCtrl` member) or like this:

```
export class HomePage {
    private salary: number;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { ... }
}
```

---

Ionic is not a typescript library but a javascript one, so their documentation is javascript and not typescript.
With javascript (when using es6 classes) you don't need to declare the members like you need to in typescript.

When the typescript code in my answer compiles into javascript it looks like this:

```
var HomePage = (function () {
    function HomePage(navCtrl) {
        this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
    }
    return HomePage;
}());
```

As you can see, here too there's no trace of the public/private, or the declaration of the members, that's just a typescript thing and it was there from (probably) the first version.

Comment: Is that a new feature of type script?  it's not in any of the ionic 2 documentation ie https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavPush/ they don't do that at all.  How would it work for a component?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score 3):

You can declare salary like this

```
export class HomePage {
  salary: number;
  constructor(navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.salary = 7;
  }
}
```

Note: No need to use `public` keyword to declare public members.

use `private salary: number;` to make it as private.

To initialize with default value use `salary: number = 10;`